# How to transform a plane into a honeycomb?

Tags: modeling

I would like to make all the convex plane shown by the red  arrow as a honeycomb surface.

I tried to use the add-on Honeycomb after having the addon *Extra Objects* enabled ( *File > User Preferences > Addons*, in the *Add Mesh* category).

In the *Add Object menu > Mesh > Extra Objects > MiscObjects > add a Honeycomb*. But i don't know how I can stick it on the surface I want to transform.

Or maybe there is another method?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The best result (in my experience anyway) is achieved with the [Tissue addon](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue)'s tesselate function. The mesh isn't perfect and you need to remove doubles, but it's still much nicer and easier to use than a shrinkwrap based workflow.

[image]

What you need is a basic mesh tile that will repeat nicely, like this one:

[image]

And hopefully a fairly evenly spaced and uniform mesh, comprised of pretty much equally sized quad faces (you can generate such a mesh with the [Remesh modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html)).

I would suggest separating the piece you want to convert into a hex grid from the rest of the mesh, tesselate, remove doubles, then re-join with the original.

To generate the tesselation:

1. Select your hex tile.
2. Then select your target object (the one you want to generate a hex grid from).
3. Go to the Tissue tab in the tools panel.
4. Click on the "Tesselate" button.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a procedural texture to render the surface as a honeycomb such as described in this answer : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78003/29586

[image: honeycomb]

[image]

This can be achieved by importing the material (using File/Append) from the Blend file provided in the above answer and assigning it to your surface. Use a Mapping node to adjust the orientation if necessary.