# How to make consistent bumpy pattern geometry

Tags: bump

Could you suggest best approach to make this geometry? Not fake texture bump but geometry one?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform a plane into a honeycomb?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66769/how-to-transform-a-plane-into-a-honeycomb)