# how to "shrinkwrap" this wrap to a cylinder

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shrinkwrap

Im making a katana, and modelling the wrap that goes around it. I finally got the shape down but i cant use shrinkwrap to shrinkwrap it to a cylinder because it comes out weird like this

[image]

Extruding wont help, heres what it looks like before:
[image]

one half of the mesh is supposed to be on top of the other, and when i shrinkwrap it, it turns the shape into a cylinder type and takes away the overlap. I can't use the curve modifier because it messes it up too.

As shown from top view:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deform object after another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object), in particular, a variation of Moonboot's answer using surface deform would be the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy way to do it with shrinwrap or anything, maybe simplify the topology then modify the shape with proportional editing activated, maybe a lattice to easily modify the whole thing. Also, it's a pattern that is repeated vertically, you coul begin with an array...