# Wrapping a text to a bend area

Tags: text-object

I want to bend a text object to a bent plane as shown in the attached picture but I do not know how to fulfill it. Any good hints, tutorials?
Many thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Do some research on the Shrinkwrap Modifier

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Comment: Thank you guy's! I'll give them a try!