# About shrinkwrap - Any way to apply it to a vertex group and move the rest the proportional distance?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

it's probably a very basic question but i have no idea how to get it and i have to say that my use of blender is quite basic.

I have this object that I want to attach to the surface of the mountain

[image]

I know that with the modifier I can join the object to the mountain, but the whole shape would be lost ... and assigning a group of vertices will only affect them, being this way:[image]

My question is if there is any way to get the remaining vertices to move while maintaining the proportion with respect to the others, something like this:[image]

I'm still investigating, but any help is more than welcome.

Thank you!

Edit: thanks for the answer, but the problem is that there would be hundreds of objects like this, they are simply a plane to create a forest effect

And the interesting thing would be not to lose the UV map so as not to have to map them all. In fact, being different, I could not even transfer the mapping.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48823/86891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many different ways, each with their own quirks:

[image]

Use two shrinkwrap modifiers, each with different distances-- one for the bottom and one for the top.

[image]

Follow a shrinkwrap on the bottom with a strong corrective smooth on the top.

[image]

Shrinkwrap the whole thing, then displace the top verts in global Z.  Might be worth making a shapekey that vertex slides the top verts all the way down to the bottom verts so they shrinkwrap to the same position.

[image]

Instead of doing it with an upright (YZ) plane, do it on a whole XY plane, then build the rest of it with solidify.  Recreate UV on shell via UV warp modifier.  Displacement lets you "solidify" in local or world axes instead of along normal.  Mask modifier, disabled in screenshot to make it easier to understand, destroys the rear vertices.

Other ideas worth considering toward your goal, but that don't answer your explicit question, are the use of particle systems or instancing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a subdivided plane, use a subdivided edge like so :

[image]

Add your shrinkwrap :

[image]

Now add a Screw Modifier set to Z axis, angle 0°, with 1 step and tweak the screw value:

[image]

Moving the source object along the X Axis :

[image]

You can add a solidify modifier after all this to add thickness to your wall :

[image]

Comment: that is quite useful thank you very much, but in this case it is not what I am looking for, let me explain myself a little better.
I will edit the question

Comment: Really dig the animation. And using the screw modifier this way is really clever :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks ! Yeah the Screw modifier is paramount to any kind of parametric modelling for me :)