# Why are project and surface deform not working?

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap, surface-deform

I am trying to make the project and deform processes described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object) to work, but in neither case do the plane or the cube deform towards the cylinder.

This:

[image]

is the plane to cylinder shrinkwrap

and this

[image]

is the cube to cylinder surface deform

The plane and cubes seem sufficiently subdivided to me:

[image]

so I'm wondering what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Make sure you keep it in order: first add the _Surface Deform_ modifier to the cube, then set the plane as target and bind the cube to the plane. Next add the _Shrinkwrap Modifier_ to the plane and set the cylinder as target.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - thanks! done that, didn't work. Cube flattens nicels on plane, but when I add shrinkwrap to the plane the effect is gone. And the project modifier doesn't work either

Comment: Your screenshot shows two cylinders next to each other, one with a plane not wrapped to it and one with a plane wrapped to it and the cube seemingly not bound to the deformed plane. How is your setup exactly? When I use the setup below and keep the order it works as expected for me.